# Matlab contour plot in 3d

Tags: matlab, contour

I have an array which include [x y z F]. I want to plot a contour which depicts every point (x,y,z) addressed with a given property F. F may be energy or something else.

How do I plot an `isosurface` contour with different f in the same figure?

I have managed to do direct modes superposition method (DMSM) from ANSYS but it seems `ansys` doesn't include this function.

Comment: have you tried "hold on" ?